# New file creation event in Windows

Tags: windows, events, filesystems

Does there any event occur in Windows when a new file is created? I want run a function in my program every time a new file or directory is created.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice [MSDN-Post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to obtain Directory-Change-Notifications. The [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx)-Syscall might be a nice starting point.

Comment: Can I use this function in qt?

Comment: AFAIK, you can use C++ with qt, so it should be possible. The MSDN example is also implemented in C++.

Comment: This is the link to the program. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i8aryc9zc4v23xo/AADu-mYq1XThx0M5Ew22T8pVa?dl=0